# IE 11 closes Bootstrap popover when scrolling

Tags: internet-explorer, bootstrap-popover

I'm using Bootstrap popover on text elements with the trigger option set to 'focus'. I've set the maximum height of the popover to 300px and set the overflow-y to auto. In IE, mouse wheel will scroll the popover, but a click will close the popover, IE handles a click to scroll the same as click. I'm trying to prevent the popover from being closed if it's being scrolled.

Here's a link to jsbin: https://jsbin.com/reyocaweri/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around for IE11's scrolling issue. the `mousedown` event is fired before the `blur` event. Knowing this I was able to set up a "scrolling" flag which I could test for before allowing the popover to hide.